# iGoogle widget for webcam?

Tags: streaming, webcam, igoogle

Does anyone know how I can best stream a webcam through an iGoogle widget?

My ideal is to actually be able to stream locally--that is, get a widget that allows me to display my computer's webcam. Is this possible?

(No, I'm not that vain. I'm using a webcam as a Security Camera, and I'd like to be able to view it, streaming, on my iGoogle console as part of an array of useful, automatic widgets that are being displayed on a wallmounted flat screen monitor.)

Answer (score 0):

Flash is likely your best bet here as it has everything you need already, however you could just use one of the many already available services and build a widget for it.
My personal preference is [uStream.tv](http://www.ustream.tv)

Answer (score 0):

Does iGoogle Widget allow iframe?

If yes then you can virtually use anything.